# Code with csv input is not working typescript javascript d3

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, d3.js

The following is the original code:

```
export function classifyTwoGaussData(numSamples: number, noise: number):
    Example2D[] {
  let points: Example2D[] = [];

  let varianceScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .5]).range([0.5, 4]);
  let variance = varianceScale(noise);

  function genGauss(cx: number, cy: number, label: number) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numSamples / 2; i++) {
      let x = normalRandom(cx, variance);
      let y = normalRandom(cy, variance);
      points.push({x, y, label});
    }
  }

  genGauss(2, 2, 1); // Gaussian with positive examples.
  genGauss(-2, -2, -1); // Gaussian with negative examples.
  return points;
}
```

Trying to replace this function with csv input:

```
function genGauss(cx: number, cy: number, label: number) {
        for (let i = 0; i < numSamples / 2; i++) {
          let x = normalRandom(cx, variance);
          let y = normalRandom(cy, variance);
          points.push({x, y, label});
        }
      }
```

As:

```
d3.csv("training.csv", function(data){
    //for (let i = 0; i < numSamples / 2; i++) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {  
      let x = parseFloat(d.input1);//,variance);
      let y = parseFloat(d.input2);  //,variance);
      let label = parseInt(d.output);
      // console.log(points);
      points.push({x, y, label});
    });
      });
```

The following is the error that I encountered:

```
bundle.js:1 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNZ".
attrFunction @ bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:4
d3_selection_each @ bundle.js:1
d3_selectionPrototype.each @ bundle.js:4
d3_selectionPrototype.attr @ bundle.js:4
AppendingLineChart.redraw @ bundle.js:8
AppendingLineChart.addDataPoint @ bundle.js:8
updateUI @ bundle.js:9
reset @ bundle.js:9
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:9
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:1
```

Please let me know what I am missing. The `csv` sample that I am trying to load is as follows:

```
input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7,output
1.20047,1.20047,1.20045,1.20045,1.200059606178815,0.0003585714285714223,-3.791789292925229e-06,-1.0
1.20088,1.20088,1.20087,1.20087,1.200329737452543,0.0003835714285714117,6.180045764568489e-07,-1.0
1.20007,1.20023,1.20007,1.20007,1.200243158301695,0.0004278571428571306,4.129903631236368e-06,0.0
1.20022,1.20023,1.20022,1.20023,1.2002387722011298,0.0004271428571428402,7.19294850670973e-06,1.0
1.20023,1.20029,1.20023,1.20029,1.2002558481340868,0.0004192857142857093,9.916424565845627e-06,1.0
1.20046,1.20046,1.20046,1.20046,1.2003238987560578,0.00042499999999998485,1.259884292315837e-05,0.0
1.20053,1.20053,1.20053,1.20053,1.2003925991707052,0.0004049999999999966,1.523257396764079e-05,0.0
1.20045,1.20072,1.20045,1.20067,1.200485066113804,0.0004164285714285794,1.794705969746539e-05,1.0
1.20073,1.20092,1.20073,1.20092,1.2006300440758693,0.000424285714285742,2.103349972108536e-05,1.0
1.2009299999999998,1.2009299999999998,1.20075,1.2008,1.2006866960505802,0.0004228571428571772,2.3925052012490654e-05,-1.0
1.20094,1.20094,1.20094,1.20094,1.200771130700387,0.000396428571428607,2.676900242219225e-05,0.0
1.20094,1.20094,1.20094,1.20094,1.200827420466924,0.0002628571428571757,2.9380206159665192e-05,0.0
1.2009299999999998,1.2009299999999998,1.20082,1.2009,1.200851613644616,0.0002557142857143352,3.156425194537858e-05,-1.0
1.2009,1.2009,1.2009,1.2009,1.2008677424297445,0.00019428571428575792,3.3289202180031105e-05,0.0
```

Comment: async loading of data

Comment: @rioV8 Than you for your comment. But I have tried using the timeout function. But it still remains the same.

Comment: no need for timeout, look for an async load tutorial or seach SO and it depends on your version of D3

Comment: @rioV8 ok I will try it. And will let you know.

Comment: @rioV8 Can you help with the async loading of the data, please?

Comment: @rioV8 I tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781156/queuing-not-getting-possible-with-d3-javascript-typescript But it didn't helped.

Comment: that is not the only SO question about async loading and it depends on your d3 version

Comment: @rioV8 I will edit the question and add the package json part where it is mentioned the dependencies